# How to update list index object value in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have list that contains the object and i want to change it.

```
  <#list Users as usr>
 /*It is not reflect into the list */
  <#assign  usr.Name="Jhone">
  </#list>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, templates shouldn't modify the data-model. So think twice if you really want to do this.

If you still want to do this, FreeMarker doesn't have explicit support for it, but if `usr` has a public `setName(String)` method in Java, you can call that: `${usr.setName("Jhone")}`.

Not sure what `/*It is not reflect into the list*/` means though. As the user object comes from the list, changing the user object will also change the user object in the list.